# Проблема из-за изменение Media ссылок

Tags: java, javafx, mediaplayer

Добрый день. В своём приложение сделал типа коллекцию музыки воспроизводимой MediaPlayer JavaFX. Чтобы внести трек надо ввести его медиа ссылку. Что вы думаете? Я внёс сегодня днём новую Media ссылку. Вечером попробовал её снова запустить и тут ничего не произошло... Ссылка изменилась на новую.. печально... У вас есть идеи как мне следить за этими media ссылками и не терять их? Или может какая-нибудь альтернатива?

К примеру вот сайт https://music.yandex.by/genre/alternative, на нём берём первый трек No Roots, берём его медиа ссылку https://s122h.storage.yandex.net/get-mp3/7d43da2c4d06b7d3dc4908e5d2aceb18/00055c3666830342/music/38/9/data-0.7:38642182160:5660630?track-id=36367574&play=false. Вот эта ссылка как раз и меняется через определённые промежутки времени. А код совершенно простой

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(url.toURI().toString())); //url это и есть наша медиа ссылка.
mediaPlayer.play;
```

Comment: Вы хоть бы код показали, что ли.

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев выложил отрывок несущий суть, кроме того выложил ещё пример трека и его медиа ссылки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача решается путем использования YandexMedia API.
https://tech.yandex.ru/audio/jsapi/
По ссылке можно найти их js-скрипт плеера, соответственно надо его расковырять, посмотреть как они формируют корректные ссылки и сделать также у себя.
Еще есть статья на хабре, хотя и более старая, чем хотелось бы, но возможно поможет - https://habrahabr.ru/post/133578/

Comment: Обязательно посмотрю, будет просто офигенно если разберусь!